# Who defines the arguments in this javascript snippet?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am just starting out with javascript and have a problem understanding this piece of (svg)code below which uses javascript for defining it's x co-ordinate and radius. I understand how data is bound etc. But my question is - For the function which takes two arguments : **d and i**, where is it defined that the first argument to the function is the dataset and the second is a counter for the circle, ie 0 for the first circle, 1 for the second and so on.

```
var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                 .data(dataset)
                 .enter()
                 .append("circle");
circles.attr("cx", function(d, i) {
            return (i * 50) + 25;
        })
       .attr("cy", h/2)
       .attr("r", function(d) {
            return d;
       });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably inside the `.attr` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is d3 and so the [d3 documentation defines what the function expects](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#attr)

*If value is a constant, then all elements are given the same attribute value; otherwise, if value is a function, then the function is evaluated for each selected element (in order), being passed the current datum d and the current index i, with the this context as the current DOM element.*

Comment: Thanks, that gives a clear explanation to my question.
But for next time, I was just wondering if there is any concept in javascript by which arguments are passed to a function without any value and their values are altered/given a value inside the function body. So the arguments that are passed initially are more like placeholders.(Just to reiterate, this is about pure javascript and not d3). I ask this because I think I have heard something of that sort, can't really recollect. And time and again, I keep bumping into functions for which I can't figure out where value was given.

Comment: If you have another question use the Ask Question button to ask it.